# PHP communication with Arduino under Windows and Linux

Tags: php, arduino

In Windows I can connect to Arduino without any problem, I can send all bytes like number (0-9) and letters (a-z). But I've got problem in Linux (ubuntu) because I can only send numbers (0-9). When I'm using same code, in Windows I can send all and in Linux I'm sending but it's not working at all.

It's my code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);  

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {

    require("php_serial.class.php");

        $serial = new phpSerial();
        $serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyACM0");
        $serial->confBaudRate(9600);
        $serial->confCharacterLength(8);
        $serial->deviceOpen();

if ($_GET['action'] == "1") {

        $serial->sendMessage("1");

} else if ($_GET['action'] == "2") {

        $serial->sendMessage("2");
}

if ($_GET['action'] == "a") {

        $serial->sendMessage("a");

} else if ($_GET['action'] == "b") {

        $serial->sendMessage("b");
}

$serial->deviceClose();

}

?>
```

In windows I need to replace "/dev/ttyACM0" to "COM3" but it's still same code. This code turn my diode on/off. If I use it in Windows I can turn on diode by typing numbers (1 on, 2 off) or letter (a = on, b = off). In Linux I only turn diode on by typing numbers...

I see Arduino is "reading" my sendbyte a or b, but it's not doing any action.

Comment: Can you give the URL for library!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made this by setting:

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "a") {

        $serial->sendMessage("aaaa");
```